# Can SDL mutex be locked twice?

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl

I was heving a weird bug in my project when I diced to test this myself, and just look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <NLF.h>
#include <SDL_mutex.h>

SDL_mutex *mutex;
void tt()
{
    printf("func\n");
    printf("tentando locar: %d\n", SDL_LockMutex(mutex));
    printf("locado\n");
}

int main(int arg, char *argc[])
{
    SDL_Thread *thread;
    mutex = SDL_CreateMutex();

    printf("locado : %d\n", SDL_LockMutex(mutex));

    thread = SDL_CreateThread(tt, "TestThread", NULL);

    printf("relocado : %d\n", SDL_LockMutex(mutex));
}
```

and here is the output:

```
locado : 0
func
relocado : 0
```

that is to say, the "mutex" is locked at first correctly, then flow gets into the thread function, and the "mutex" to your thing and the thread gets locked. But note that I do not unlock the "mutex". then I try to lock again in main thread, and it works... why? I should get a deadlock .-.
wierd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockMutex) states:

> SDL mutexes are recursive.

Which means you can lock it several times in the same thread (and you'll need to unlock it the same number of times that you locked it in that thread to unlock it for another thread)

Comment: maan, what a lack of attention of mine.
Thank you

Comment: And typical non-recursive mutexes don't specify the behavior if you attempt to lock them mutex recursively. They may deadlock. The second lock operation may be a no-op. They may crash.